# How Can I Hide IP from nmap scanning

Tags: linux, security, networking, nmap

How can I hide IP from Nmap scanning?

Thanks in advance (sorry if my English so bad)

Answer (score 1):

The most popular services are: [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview), [Proxy Chains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) and [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent your IP Address from being leaked, you could use a proxy, VPN, or other service.

A proxy simply forwards your traffic through another server. There are web proxies and proxies for your whole system. [Hide.Me](https://hide.me/en/proxy) and [HMA](https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy) both have web proxies. [SamAir.RU](https://premproxy.com/) has proxies that you can set up through your proxy settings. Proxies are typically free, but not as secure as VPNs.

A VPN (Virtual Private Network) sets up a secure, encrypted connection between you and another target, which your traffic is tunneled through. Some popular VPNs are [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), [ExpressVPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/), [NordVPN](https://nordvpn.com/), [Hotspot Shield](https://www.hotspotshield.com/), and [VyprVPN](https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn). These all provide different costs and security, do some research before using one. Some keep IP/history logs, which kind of defeats the purpose.

You can also use other services, like [Tor (The Onion Router)](https://www.torproject.org/) and [FreeNet](https://freenetproject.org). Tor uses onion routering, or multiple layers of encryption, goes through multiple servers, etc., and has been super secure for years. However, the NSA cracked Tor and can now view people's browsing and IPs. FreeNet is similar to Tor, but hasn't been cracked by the NSA (yet).